# How to speed up query from 2 tables with 400 million rows each

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, sql-server-2019

I have 2 tables, `trans_details_sell` and `trans_details_buy`, and both have 400 millions rows each. These 2 table are linked up with a unique column call `cdr_id`.

A 3rd table is `deal_master`, which is the master table only have about 300 master records.

My query will be using `deal_master` to link up `trans_details_sell` to get the revenue and at the mean time using `trans_details_sell` to link up `trans_details_buy` to get the cost (with `cdr_id`).

- `deal_master` is using `lcr_zone` and `customer_interconnect` to link with `trans_details_sell` and its columns, `lcr_zone` and `sig_netgroup`.
- `trans_details_sell` has clustered primary key `(lcr_zone, sig_netgroup, cdr_id)`
- `trans_details_buy` has clustered primary key `(lcr_zone, sig_netgroup, cdr_id)`

Both tables have the same data structure but 1 for sell records one for buy records, and also both having CDR_ID as non-clustered unique index.

My main query, when only involve 2 table which is `deal_master` and `trans_details_sell`, the speed is ok (to get the revenue), but when add in `trans_details_buy` to get the cost, it will be extremely slow.

My SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    m.agreement_no, m.status, m.sales_person, m.swap_carrier, 
    m.swap_commitment, m.zone, m.lcr_zone, m.customer_interconnect, 
    SUBSTRING(CAST(m.start_pos AS nvarchar), 1, 4) + '-' +
       SUBSTRING(CAST(m.start_pos AS nvarchar), 5, 2) + '-' +
       SUBSTRING(CAST(m.start_pos AS nvarchar), 7, 2) start_date, 
    SUBSTRING(CAST(m.end_pos AS nvarchar), 1, 4) + '-' +
       SUBSTRING(CAST(m.end_pos AS nvarchar), 5, 2) + '-' +
       SUBSTRING(CAST(m.end_pos AS nvarchar), 7, 2) end_date, 
    m.target_minutes, m.target_sell_rate, m.target_buy_rate, 
    m.target_sales, m.target_cost, m.target_profit, 
    SUM(s.quantized_duration) / 60 DG_minute, 
    SUM(s.charge) DG_sales, SUM(b.charge) DG_cost
FROM 
    deal_master m, trans_details_sell s, trans_details_buy b
WHERE
    m.lcr_zone = s.lcr_zone 
    AND m.customer_interconnect = s.sig_netgroup 
    AND m.swap_commitment = 'Sell' 
    AND s.cdr_id = b.cdr_id 
    AND s.start_position BETWEEN m.start_pos AND m.end_pos
GROUP BY
    m.agreement_no, m.status, m.sales_person, m.swap_carrier, 
    m.swap_commitment, m.zone, m.lcr_zone, m.customer_interconnect, 
    m.start_pos, m.end_pos, m.target_minutes, m.target_sell_rate, 
    m.target_buy_rate, m.target_sales, m.target_cost, m.target_profit
ORDER BY 
    1
```

deal_master :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[deal_master]
(
    [agreement_no] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [status] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [sales_person] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [swap_carrier] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [start_pos] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [end_pos] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [swap_commitment] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [zone] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [target_minutes] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
    [target_sell_rate] [decimal](13, 11) NULL,
    [target_buy_rate] [decimal](13, 11) NULL,
    [supplier_interconnect] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [customer_interconnect] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [target_sales] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [target_cost] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [target_profit] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
    [partner] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [lcr_zone] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_deal_master] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [lcr_zone] ASC,
    [customer_interconnect] ASC,
    [supplier_interconnect] ASC,
    [start_pos] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

trans_details_sell:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[trans_details_sell]
(
    [cdr_id] [nchar](12) NOT NULL,
    [rate] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [zone] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [charge] [decimal](13, 11) NOT NULL,
    [quantized_duration] [numeric](8, 0) NOT NULL,
    [sig_carrier_group] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [sig_netgroup] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [lcr] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [lcr_zone] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [per_min_chg] [decimal](13, 11) NOT NULL,
    [trans_type] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [start_position] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [end_position] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [filename] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_trans_details_sell] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [lcr_zone] ASC,
    [sig_netgroup] ASC,
    [cdr_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

trans_details_buy:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[trans_details_sell]
(
    [cdr_id] [nchar](12) NOT NULL,
    [rate] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [zone] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [charge] [decimal](13, 11) NOT NULL,
    [quantized_duration] [numeric](8, 0) NOT NULL,
    [sig_carrier_group] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [sig_netgroup] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [lcr] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [lcr_zone] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [per_min_chg] [decimal](13, 11) NOT NULL,
    [trans_type] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [start_position] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [end_position] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [filename] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_trans_details_sell] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [lcr_zone] ASC,
    [sig_netgroup] ASC,
    [cdr_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: You mention SQL Server in your question, but you tagged the question [tag:mysql]. Which database brand are you really using? Tagging your question accurately will help get the attention of people who are able to give the best answer for the database you are using.

Comment: Please publish table definitions and execution plan as text.

Comment: I know I can merger trans_details_sell and trans_details_buy to 1 table, but for some reasons I opt not to, so is there any method to speed it up? Many thanks

Comment: Is `cdr_id` unique? Is it indexed?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, although not in the DDL, he did mention the buy/sell tables "both having CDR_ID as non-clustered unique index."

Comment: _both having CDR_ID as non-clustered unique index_ This belongs in your DDL, not as a comment buried in your description. If that is the case, then the primary key serves no useful purpose except for clustering. <jeepers!>

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables (here in your `CAST` statements) and parameters that you use

Answer (score 0):

The query only needs `charge` from `trans_detail_buy`, so add it as an included column on the unique index on `clr_id`

```
create unique index ix_clr_id 
 on trans_details_buy(clr_id) 
 include (charge)
```

Otherwise the `clr_id` is used to look up the row locator `(lcr_zone, sig_netgroup, cdr_id)` which is used to seek the clustered index to find the `charge`.

Or if they _buy and _sell always have the same `lcr_zone` and `sig_netgroup` for each `clr_id`, then join `trans_details_buy` on all three columns to bypass the index on `clr_id`.

Comment: Thanks for your good efforts. After I added and included, it take 5min and 24sec to come out the result. It is still too long time, I think I will create an additional field which is [charge] field to the trans_details_sell table.